# powershell outputing results to a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to use Powershell V2.0 to write the contents of a SQL query to a file. I can successfully use the Write-Host CMDlet to write to the console screen but when I change to Write-Output, only one result is returned in the test.txt file (instead of about 700). Why could this be?

```
 foreach ($row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows){ 
    $name = $row[0].ToString().Trim()
    Write-Output $name >test.txt
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're redirecting to the output file using > (instead of >>) on every record.  This is causing the file to get re-written with each record, and you're left with just the last record in the output file.

This should work better:

```
&{
  foreach ($row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows){ 
  $row[0].ToString().Trim()
  } }| set-content test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting the one line (and it's the last result) because the `>` operator overwrites. `>>` appends.

But a more efficient way (untested) to get the same result is:

```
$DataSet.Tables[0].Rows|select-object -expandproperty NAMEOFFIRSTCOLUMN|out-file test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks it's asking me to supply a parameter for the value each time now.. I may need to do some string manipulation so your suggested method may not work